# Bug nas medalhas do SOPT com sub-domínio meta.pt

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Percebi que ao utilizar o domínio da comunidade https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, minhas medalhas perdem a referência e vão para o número 1, voltando apenas ao clicar no quadro de realizações.

Comment: O sopt e o meta são dois sites diferentes a contagem das medalhas é diferente também. O primeiro é para perguntas tecnicas o segundo é para perguntas sobre o sopt, como bugs ou discussões/debates.

Comment: Ok, obrigado,@rray